# If $\Delta s=(\Delta u)^2$, what is $\nabla s?$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm having trouble integrating $(\Delta u)^2$. If it was $\Delta u$ the primitive would just be first derivative $\nabla u.$

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You have [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation).
That is, $\Delta s=f$ where $f=(\Delta u)^2$.

The solution given by wiki is:
$$s(\mathbf r)=-\iiint \frac{(\Delta u(\mathbf r'))^2}{4\pi\|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'\|}\,d^3\mathbf r'$$